# Interpretation of finite abelian group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ a *finite abelian etale* group $k$-scheme. There are two interpretations of finiteness here:

1. The etale $k$-morphism $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,k$ is finite;
2. For a scheme $T$, the $T$-points $G(T)$ is a finite abelian group.

Which one is more probable? Are both reasonable interpretations?

Also, we define a $G$-torsor over a scheme $X$ to be a *finite* $k$-morphism $Y \rightarrow X$, such that the right $k$-action of $G$ on $Y$ is isomorphic to the fiber product $Y \times_X Y$. In this case, I want to be sure that this finiteness condition has nothing to do with $G$ being finite in the sense of (2) right?

Comment: Usually by a finite $k$-group scheme one means a group scheme which is a finite $k$-scheme. But I haven't done algebraic geometry in a while and am not sure if your interpretations are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the first condition. The second condition is too strong because $T$ need not be connected. For example, if $G$ is the constant group scheme with value some nontrivial finite abelian group $A$ (which we certainly want to be an example), then there are at least $2^n$ morphisms $T \to G$ (hence elements of $G(T)$) where $n$ is the number of connected components of $T$. So we can take $T$ to be a scheme with infinitely many connected components (say a disjoint union of infinitely many copies of $\text{Spec } k$) and then $G(T)$ will be infinite.

Comment: Would $G(T)$ always be finite if one takes connected finite group schemes $G$?

Comment: @Qi: no. If $G$ is nontrivial then there are at least $2$ morphisms $G \to G$ (the identity and the constant morphism with constant value the identity of $G$) so you can run the same argument above with $T$ the disjoint union of infinitely many copies of $G$.